# Вывод данных SQLITE в форме списка (python)

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite

Возможно вопрос покажется не совсем корректным, но всё же. Есть блок кода, который обращается к базе и возвращает одну запись. Эта запись в форме кортежа заносится в переменную.

Вопрос в чём. Как мне из этого кортежа достать только два первых значения?

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name LIKE ?"
cursor.execute(sql, ('%'+query+'%',))
result = cursor.fetchall()
if not result:
    return bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пользователь в системе не найден.')
else:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES (?,?)", (result[0], result[1],))
    conn.commit()
```

ВЫВОД SELECT:

> ```
> [(test, 'test', 'test', 'test')]
> ```

То есть SELECT вернул 4 значения, но мне нужно всего 2.

Comment: дружище,  fetchall() выбирает все записи, а не одну.
поэтому result[0]  -  это вся первая строка.

Comment: Как тогда лучше вернуть? fetchone()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name LIKE ?"
cursor.execute(sql, ('%'+query+'%',))
result = cursor.fetchall()
if not result:
    return bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пользователь в системе не найден.')
else:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES (?,?)", (result[0][0], result[0][1],))
    conn.commit()
```